# How I can change value in column by a value of dictionary with corresponding key ? Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, opencsv, read.csv

I have file .csv, and I want change value in column 07 by a value in dictionary if the value in column is matched with the key in dictionary

```
Dictionary:  
state = {'WA': 'Western Australia', 'NM': 'New Mexico', 'GA': 'Georgia', 'SC': 'South Carolina', 'FL': 'Florida'}
```

```
fr = open ('CarRentalData.csv', 'r') #read file csv
reader = csv.reader(fr)
header = next(reader)

fw = open ('CarRentalData_clean.csv', 'w') # new file will be written
writer = csv.writer(fw)
writer.writerow(header) #write header

clean_data = []
for row in reader:
    
    

    clean_data.append(row)
    writer.writerow(row)

fr.close
fw.close
```

```
Example: if my value in column [7] is WA, then it is matched with key in dictionary 'state' and that value will be changed to Western Australia
```

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of the `CarRentalData.csv` file ?

Comment: Is `WA` really `'Western Australia'` as the rest of the codes are US states and in that case `WA` would be `Washingtiion`. See my 'answer' for a suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below. Not tested as the `CarRentalData.csv` data was not provided in question.

```
state = {'WA': 'Western Australia', 'NM': 'New Mexico', 'GA': 'Georgia', 'SC': 'South Carolina', 'FL': 'Florida'}

with open ('CarRentalData.csv', 'r') as fr:
    reader = csv.reader(fr)
    header = next(reader)

    with open ('CarRentalData_clean.csv', 'w') as fw:
        writer = csv.writer(fw)
        writer.writerow(header)

        clean_data = []
        for row in reader:
            if state.get(row[7]): # Test whether column value matches key in dict.
                row[7] = state[row[7]) # If it does change the column value to the dict value.
            clean_data.append(row)
        writer.writerows[clean_data]
```

Use context managers `with` as they automatically close the files. Also use `writerows` to write the `clean_data` list all at once.